# PHP - mysql_fetch_object with class name not working

Tags: php, class, activerecord

I am trying to build a custom ActiveRecord class and am trying to return MySQL results in an object. The object will be the model.
Here's what I'm doing:

```
while($object = mysql_fetch_object($result, $this->_model)) {
  foreach($object as $key => $val) {
    if($this->is_serialized($val)) $object->$key = unserialize($val);
  }
  $return_value[] = $object;
}
```

If I do a print_r() on the result, I get an empty class (no variables have been set or anything).
Here is my model:

```
class User extends ActiveRecord {
  public $_hasOne = "Profile";

  public $_required = array('full_name', 'user_name', 'password', 'country');
  public $_unique = array('full_name', 'user_name');

}
```

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong!

EDIT: Fixed it in the end. At the beginning of my Activerecord class I had this:

```
$fields = $this->query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM " . $this->_table);
while($field = mysql_fetch_assoc($fields)) { 
  $this->_columns[] = $field['Field'];
  $this->$field['Field'] = null;
}
```

Which was setting all the values to NULL!
Bit of a silly mistake. It's now:

```
$fields = $this->query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM " . $this->_table);
while($field = mysql_fetch_assoc($fields)) { 
  $this->_columns[] = $field['Field'];
  if(!isset($this->$field['Field'])) $this->$field['Field'] = null;
}
```

Comment: Is it actually returning something? Try a `var_dump( mysql_fetch_assoc );`.

Answer (score 0):

Stupid question, but `$this->_model` is `"User"` right (I'd echo that value, it might have gotten unset somehow).

After that, your class should have fields by the same names as the columns which you want to represent. So:

```
class Foo
{
   private $id;
   public $val;

   public function __toString(){ return "$this->id => $this->val"; }
}
mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
$q =  mysql_query('SELECT 1 as id, 2 as val FROM DUAL');
$foo = mysql_fetch_object( $q, 'Foo' );
echo $foo; // 1 => 2
```

Next, you can't iterate over an object. You need to iterate over object properties:

```
foreach(get_object_vars($object) as $key => $val) {
   if($this->is_serialized($val)) $object->$key = unserialize($val);
}
```

Comment: 1) Yes. $this->_model is "User". I echoed it and made sure and yes, it is indeed "User".
2) If I override it and set it to say "Profile", it works and sets the values.
3) I tried setting the fields in the model and that didn't make a difference.

Comment: Could it be to do with the fact that User extends Activerecord? Since the mysql_fetch_object is in the Activerecord class.

Comment: @Bradley Since I don't know which ActiveRecord you're using (the ActiveRecord has an ActiveRecord namespace, but no class by that name), I can't say, but the above code is working.

Comment: @Bradley Then I can't comment unless I know more about the actual code of ActiveRecord

Comment: Okay. Could I upload it somewhere so you could look?